# Rails + Read XLSX or CSV without fixed headers and key value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails trying to read XLSX / CSV file without fixed headers.

For example

1st CSV File, the header will be like user_id, email, dob

2nd CSV File, the header will be like user_id, username, email

So the system should manage to read them properly and should create proper json like

For the First File, JSON will be like

```
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "email": "example@eample.com",
  "dob": "2001-01-01",
}
```

For the Second File, JSON will be like

```
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "email": "example@eample.com",
  "username": "example"
}
```

Comment: Do you want separate rows for each row in each file or merged together somehow (as your example). If merged, then how should they be merged? By user_id? What if the email corresponding to a certain user_id is different in the 2 files?

Comment: The CSV class in ruby can create an array of arrays when reading a CSV file. Simply use the header row array to set the keys for a hash using every value row array. Reading an xlsx file will require a gem like roo -- but will work pretty much the same way.

Comment: @SiimLiiser: Sorry for the confusion. JSON was just an example. Here I want to process 2 different files at different times. As per the first file, I want json as per the headers and new json as per the second file headers.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```rb
require 'csv'

file1 = <<CSV1
user_id,email,dob
1,bob@bob.com,1998/12/1
2,alice@alice.com,2001/1/2
CSV1

file2 = <<CSV2
user_id,email,name
1,bob@bob.com,bob
2,alice@alice.com,alice
CSV2

# make an array of the rows as hashes,
# e.g. [ {"user_id"=>"1", "email"=>"bob@bob.com", "dob"=>"1998/12/1"},
#        {"user_id"=>"2", "email"=>"alice@alice.com", "dob"=>"2001/1/2"} ]
def csv_to_array(csv_string)
  CSV.parse(csv_string, headers: true).map(&:to_h)
end

a1 = csv_to_array(file1)
a2 = csv_to_array(file2)

# now zip the two arrays, then merge each
puts a1.zip(a2).map{|a| a[0].merge(a[1])}.inspect
# => [{"user_id"=>"1", "email"=>"bob@bob.com", "dob"=>"1998/12/1", "name"=>"bob"},
#     {"user_id"=>"2", "email"=>"alice@alice.com", "dob"=>"2001/1/2", "name"=>"alice"}]
```